# FOSUserBundle Entity with ManyToOne relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have AbstractUser super class that extends FOSUser, then I have entities that extends AbstractUser with fields related to that class. For instance Customer has ManyToOne relation to City entity.

Now when I try to log-in with FOSUser login form I'm getting error:

.... SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.city' in 'field list'

Of course there is no city field in the users table because it's relation column named city_id. Can anybody shed some light for me why doctrine builds query like this? Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Here is related code parts.

AbstractUser:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"admin"="Admin", "customer"="Customer", "seller"="Seller"})
 */
abstract class AbstractUser extends FOSUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Customer:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customer extends AbstractUser {

    ....

    /**
     * @var City $city
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="customers")
     */
    private $city;

    ....
}
```

City:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="city")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class City
{
    ....

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $customers
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="city")
     */
    private $customers;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the visibility on `$city` and `$customers` has to be protected, not private.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for disturbance. This is my fault that I turned on doctrine cache (and impressed with results btw).
Almost scratched the hole in my head while trying to understand why this is happening. Luckily I ran into another error something woith doctrine and apc. Voila! That gave me a clue where to look.

Comment: use comment please if it's not an answer.